# Autofill field on a click using django and javascript

Tags: javascript, python

I started to make a code to autofill a field when I click in a value that I already used in old requests so I did this:

to get the value from the loop in the javascript code:

```
{% for x in request.session.query_x reversed %}
var x_point = "{{x}}"
{% endfor %}

function autoFill() {
  document.getElementById('input1').value = x_point;
}
```

the list was created from a loop and I want to click in each value at time to fill the field (html) - I got the list and everything works well in this part:

```
  {% for x in request.session.query_x reversed %}
      X: <a href="#" onClick="autoFill();">{{x}}</a><br>
  {% endfor %}
```

the field that will receive the value:

```
<div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls mb-0 pb-2"><label>X</label><input class="form-control" type="text" id="input1" required="" placeholder="X"<br>
```

The point is that any value from the loop that I click I got the first value from the loop not the right one from the position. What I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting `x_point` value on each iteration:

```
{% for x in request.session.query_x reversed %}
    var x_point = "{{x}}"
{% endfor %}
```

Send event as parameter, so you can avoid link default behaviour and get inner text:

```
{% for x in request.session.query_x reversed %}
    X: <a href="#" onClick="autoFill(event);">{{x}}</a><br>
{% endfor %}

function autoFill(e) {
    // Avoid default link behaviour (scroll to #)
    e.preventDefault();
    // Assign link text
    document.getElementById('input1').value = e.target.innerText;
}
```

Comment: Triby, this example works very well for this case. But another question, if I have one more variable with the same behaviour, which is the best way to autofill two fields at time from two different loops?

Comment: Can't tell you if I can't see some code, but you can use dataset to store values in same item and grab it to autofill 2 or more elements with just one click: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset

Comment: I will look in this documentation, you really helped me a lot. I did two functions based in your example and with this I can autofill bot fields but one each time (2 clicks) my intention is to populate the both fields with just one click (get the valeu from the first loop and the second, then populate the field)

Comment: Try with dataset, if you have any trouble, I'll be glad to try to help you.